# How to fix the error "E: Unable to locate package wireless-tools" in termux

Tags: root, pkg-config, termux, android-wireless, ipconfig

The answer is:

We get this error when we try to install the wireless tools in termux using the below command

> `pkg install wireless-tools`

This is because the **termux-root-packages** repository are not subscribed. To subscribe to the root repository, please use the below comand.

> `pkg install root-repo`

Once the root repository is installed, you can install the wireless tools without an error.

> `pkg install wireless-tools`

Hope this info helps.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! This site uses question & answer format. The part you posted is the question part, can you seperate your answer and post it as a seperate answer below?